# Rethinkdb full search by contains text

Tags: database, nosql, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, rethinkdbdash

I have a lot of tries to search by same part of the string in the rethinkdb but I can not do it yet.
And I receive this error:

```
db.table("jobs")
        .filter(db.row("title").contains(title))
        .filter({ locationCode: location })
        .run()
        .then(result => {
            res.json({
                result,
                meta: {
                    title,
                    location,
                    count: result.length,
                },
            });
        });
```

Error:

```
Unhandled rejection ReqlLogicError: Cannot convert STRING to SEQUENCE in:
r.table("jobs").filter(r.row("title").contains("front")).filter({
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  locationCode: "216"
})
```

And I'm using the **rethinkdbdash** library.
please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the downcase and match instead of contains is worked for me:

```
.filter(db.row("title").downcase().match(title.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 2):

**contains** is used to check if an element is present in a sequence

**match** is to be used when you do string search